# Somar valores com codigos diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, script, sql-server-2012

boa noite, tenho o script abaixo:

```
SELECT Month([doacao_total].[doacao_sdt_data]) AS MES, 
       Year([doacao_total].[doacao_sdt_data])  AS Ano, 
       Sum(doacao_total.doacao_mon_valor)      AS [Valor_doacao], 
       Count(doacao_total.pessoa_lng_codigo)   AS [Quantidade doações], 
       doacao_total.origem_doacao_lng_codigo, 
       doa_origem_doacao.origem_doacao_vch_descricao 
FROM   doacao_total 
       LEFT JOIN doa_origem_doacao 
              ON doacao_total.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 
                 doa_origem_doacao.origem_doacao_lng_codigo 
WHERE  Year([doacao_total].[doacao_sdt_data]) = 2019 
GROUP  BY Month([doacao_total].[doacao_sdt_data]), 
          Year([doacao_total].[doacao_sdt_data]), 
          doacao_total.origem_doacao_lng_codigo, 
          doa_origem_doacao.origem_doacao_vch_descricao 
ORDER  BY Year([doacao_total].[doacao_sdt_data]), 
          Month([doacao_total].[doacao_sdt_data]), 
          doacao_total.origem_doacao_lng_codigo
```

Rodando este script tenho resultado como na imagem SUM_1, porem, preciso somar alguns códigos de origem para o resultado ficar conforme a imagem SUM_2.

os codigo que preciso somar sao:

1 + 2 + 7 + 9 - boleto
8 - Boleto site
6 - Dinheiro
10 - Debito
11 - Recido
12 - Deposito
23 - Cartao

[image: sum_1]

[image: sum_2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use o case, no campo de origem:
No final seria o ideal fazer um group by DESCRICAO, mas nos meus testes não deu certo.

```
SELECT Month(d.[doacao_sdt_data])   AS MES, 
       Year(d.[doacao_sdt_data])    AS Ano, 
       Sum(d.doacao_mon_valor)      AS 'Valor_doacao', 
       Count(d.pessoa_lng_codigo)   AS 'Quantidade doações', 
       (case    when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 1 or d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 2 or d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 7 or d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo,  = 9 then 'BOLETO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 8 then 'BOLETO SITE',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 6 then 'DINHEIRO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 10 then 'DEBITO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 11 then 'RECIBO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 12 then 'DEPOSITO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 23 then 'CARTAO') as 'DESCRICAO'
FROM doacao_total as d
WHERE  Year(d.[doacao_sdt_data]) = 2019 
GROUP  BY Month(d.[doacao_sdt_data]), 
          Year(d.[doacao_sdt_data]), 
                (case   when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 1 or d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 2 or d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 7 or d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo,  = 9 then 'BOLETO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 8 then 'BOLETO SITE',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 6 then 'DINHEIRO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 10 then 'DEBITO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 11 then 'RECIBO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 12 then 'DEPOSITO',
                when d.origem_doacao_lng_codigo = 23 then 'CARTAO') as 'DESCRICAO'
ORDER  BY Year(d.[doacao_sdt_data]), 
          Month(d.[doacao_sdt_data])
```

Comment: Consegui com este codigo mesmo. Obrigado.